# mysql group_concat function using sub-query in condition

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysqli-multi-query

### mysql group_concat function using sub-query in condition  I want to try as below :

```
SELECT * FROM  prologic WHERE ID IN (

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT ID ) from ( 
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT ID )ID
FROM  `prologic` 
GROUP BY Vendor_Code
HAVING COUNT( * ) >1
)c
)
```

Please guide me to solve it.

Comment: Sorry, what is "condation" and what is "Blew"?

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM prologic WHERE ID IN (
SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM  prologic 
GROUP BY Vendor_Code
HAVING COUNT( * ) >1
)